# what is the difference between these pattern of jquery defered call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

I am trying to call some asynchronous function like this. Why in case A and case B I failed but success in case C?

**Case A**

```
firstCall()// try to get esstential parameters(a defered)
.fail(function(){
   //failed :call login function again wait user to input login credential(also a defered)
})
.always(function() {
    //show welcome message
})
```

In this case when fail just start to execute, the always part just execute without waiting.

**Case B**

```
firstCall()// try to get esstential parameters(a defered)
.fail(function(){
    //failed :call login function again wait user to input login 
})
.done(function() {
    //show welcome message
})
```

In this case,if the fail part get executed ,but the done part never get executed.

**Case C**

```
firstCall()// try to get esstential parameters(a defered)
.then(null,function(){
     //failed :call login function again wait user to input login 
})
.always(function() {
    //show welcome message
})
```

In this case, the `then` part act as the fail part, and always can run after `then` finished.

I am not sure why is the case happening.Can someone explained further? Thanks

Comment: What does `firstCall()` return? What version of jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All external quotes in this answer are taken from the [**jQuery Deferred Object documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or the corresponding method documentation linked therein.

---

**CASE A**

> *"...the always part just execute without waiting.*"

Let''s take a look at the documentation for [`.fail()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/):

> ...`deferred.fail()` returns the deferred object, other methods of the deferred object can be chained to this one...

The `.fail()` method returns the *original deferred object* rather than opening a new promise. What this means is that any events chained to it, while they will run sequentially, do not inherently wait for the previous ones to finish. Your `.fail()` will not be awaited, but executed *instantly*.

Any callback methods you'd like to attach would have to be chained to the inner function, creating a nested cycle of deferred objects - you can imagine how ugly that might get if we started going three or four callbacks deep.

Luckily, **`.then()` exists for this exact purpose!** *But more on that in Case C...*

---

**CASE B** - *"In this case,if the fail part get executed ,but the done part never get executed."*

`.done()` and `.fail()` are **opposites**. Only one of them will fire for any single deferred object, based on whether it succeeds or fails.

> **`deferred.done()`**
>
> Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is **resolved**.

> **`deferred.fail()`**
>
> Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is **rejected**.

---

**CASE C**

> **`.then()`**
>
> Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is **resolved**, **rejected**, or **still in progress**.

`.then()` and `.fail()` both handle a rejected deferred object.

However there is a major difference:

> **As of jQuery 1.8**, the `deferred.then()` method returns a new promise...

`.then()` *returns a **new promise***, whereas `.fail()` *does not*. This means that any methods chained to the `.then()` method will await its completion much like the original deferred object.

---

**Summary:**

If you're trying to make sequential awaited calls, use `.then()`. This will allow you to progress through the chain as a sequence of new promises, while maintaining the status and values of the original deferred object.

If you're finished making sequential calls and you're ready to "close" the deferred object, use a method that returns the deferred object, like `.done()`, `.fail()`, or`.always()`.